# Best code organizations for such project type

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, business-logic, expert-system

I have a set of parameters and coefficients.

It looks like this:

```
param1
{
    Name:blabla;
    PossibleValues:[{'lalalla1',0.9},{'lalala2',0.8},{'lalal3',0.7},{'lallal4',1.0}]; 
    // where lalalla1 is name, 0.9 is coefficient    
}
```

and logic like this(set of rules):

When value of `param1` is lalala2 then value of `param2` could be only 'dsfsd'

When value of `param3` is 'dsfsda' then `param4` doesnt exists.

When value of `param4` is 'dsafsad' then we use that formula:

```
Sum = param2.value.coeff*param6.value.coeff
```

And so on.

What is best code organization for such task types? For UI i want use knockoutjs because of i have many dependency elements. But also i am going to do separate layer for business logic and UI and write some tests. Another thing which i want implement is declarative rules. What do you think about Rx? Could it help me? Or do you know any other cool libs?

Answer (score 0):

It is only the first two parameters, but the pattern you need is the same.  http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/39b9d/4/

You want to implement dependendObservable functions as described on http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/dependentObservables.html

I think this answers your question, if not, please leave comment.